Google apps script not reading columns as variable
I work in a school and we are using a variant of TJHouston's script to manage invoices sent out to people who use the autoshop's service. The guy who set it all up retired and he made a copy of all of his documents related to the invoicing system. The process consists of:

A google form
the sheet that is attached to the form
a document that the script uses as a template to fill out and mail to 'customers'
Here is the beginning of the script (I've included up to line 16, it fails consistently at line 13). I've numbered them manually here for clarity.

1// TJ Houston tjhouston.com (tj@tjhouston.com)
2// Bus Conduct Report
3// Get template from Google Docs and name it
4 var docTemplate = "1r1jI_7s6KU5vRwZGjeQnzfGvizmgOq2IiY2z8KGxxMY"; // *** replace with your template ID ***
5 var docName = "SCHSAutoShopInvoice";
6
7// When Form Gets submitted
8 function onFormSubmit(e) {
9  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
10  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
11
12  //Get information from form and set as variables
13  var keyDate = e.values[0];
14  var keyName = e.values[1];
15  var keybName = e.values[26];
16  var keyMail = e.values[2];

After having put in the document template ID and (later on in the script) the folder it's supposed to dump to, the script keeps failing at line 13.
  var keyDate = e.values[0];
It's like it isn't reading the spreadsheet's columns as the variables. I suppose it could be failing later on in the script and it's just throwing the error at line 13. Here's a screenie of the beginning few columns of the sheet the form fills
enter image description here
The odd thing is using the forums in his folder system worked fine, just once you copy them all and the script seems to fail. It's like the script can't find the sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've ensured all of the google ID's are correct, I moved files out of the organization's shared folders and into my own and adjusted permissions in case it had something to do with that (it didn't help). Nothing I adjust seems to fix this error:
enter image description here

If you are trying to run the function onFormSubmit(e) manually, it will always give you error as this function is designed to run automatically on form submit via trigger. Just submit the form after filling the values and check the trigger section if you have created the trigger to this function as you said that you have created copy of sheet. Let me know the outcome, I will help you further.

I'm an idiot. I wasn't aware there was a trigger section (I messed around with deployments before, thinking that might be an issue). I'm now FAR further into the script before a failure happens. I'll give debugging a go from here and report back.

No Bueno, stuck again.
Error Exception: Invalid email: .
at onFormSubmit(Code:112:9)
From what I see:
16  var keyMail = e.values[2];
It should be loading the email value (in that column) to variable keyMail. There's a pile of stuff in between, but essentially a PDF is created, stored, attached and sent.
109 // Attach PDF and send the email
110 var subject = "Auto Shop invoice";
111 var body = "Here is the Invoice for " + keyName +keybName + ". Payment link will be sent soon.";
112 MailApp.sendEmail(keyMail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

Ugh, that comment formatted awfully. Sorry. I numbered lines again so it can be read a bit easier hopefully. The gist of it is: the email format in that column (keyMail) seems to be just fine. I can't see why it would be considered an invalid email.

Add sheet structure sample and error message as text, not as images.

Thanks again to DirtyHands for the suggestions. I was triggering the script manually with RUN thinking I could test it. I also didn't have a trigger set up properly on it. That suggestion let me get far enough to figure out why the rest of the script wasn't working properly. It's now working like clockwork in a shared-drive so shouldn't need to be moved again. Cheers

Based on what you said in the comments and your screenshot, can you try changing keyMail variable to
var keyMail = e.values[3];

it looks like it's in the fourth column, but it's hard to tell without seeing into the spreadsheet/form itself.

Thanks, that was it, the form was edited. One of the form questions was deleted, then re-entered, but in doing so it put another column in at the wrong spot. Once I moved e.values[26] to the 27th column in the sheet it the script started parsing it properly. Thanks again!!
